# Synchronous cross-domain request?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, cordova

I need to send a request to a webservice interface in different domain from html page. Sometimes, a synchronous request is needed. For example: login with username and password  and get response after the confirmation of webservice.

However, I used jsonp which was found that it could not do a synchronous request.
   (Both the html page and webservice are under my control)

Any good idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why does it need to be synchronous? Can use success callback of request to perform next step depending on response

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried to use success callback but there's no responce at all. The ajax method return the undefined value before the webservice set a value

Comment: show more code, last comment doesn't make sense without seeing what you are doing

Comment: @charlietfl

function login() {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: KnutBase.getServiceUrl() + "ServiceInterface/HmsPlannerWebService.asmx/AuthenticateLogin",
        data: { username: username, password: password },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            result = response.result;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

Comment: code should be added to anser in a code block where it is readable and easy for people reading the question to see it...  you can't return an AJAX value from a function. Not using callbacks properly

Comment: @charlietfl Could you please give me a simple example about "using callbacks properly to return a value". Thanks really

Comment: did you lok at my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') you can just use a standard non async $.ajax object.

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
<html>
...
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function()
    {
        $("#someID").on('click', function()
        {
            var username = 'username';
            var passwd = 'password';

            $.ajax(
            {
                type:'post,
                dataType:'json',
                url:'http://yoursite.com/web-service.php',
                data:{username:username,password:passwd},
                async:false,
                success:function(data){},
                error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi dan, thanks for your help. I have noticed the CORS. In my asp.net webservice, i tried to do it like this: Edit web.config, add a tag <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>      Howerver, it did not work. Any place was wrong?

Comment: In ASP it would be Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Answer (score 0):

`async:false` is deprecated and for good reason.

Your login function needs to be refactored so that you consume the response data in the success callback.

Your code needs to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
    /* other options*/
     success:function( response){
          if( response.status=='ok'){
             /* run sucessful login code*/
          }else{
             /* message to user*/
          }
     }

})
```