# GM.xmlHttpRequest `synchronous` option not working

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

The following code creates an alert with the content `undefined`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 188765
// @version  1
// @grant    GM.xmlHttpRequest
// @include  http*//markasoftware.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

alert(typeof GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  url: 'https://google.com',
  synchronous: true,
  method: 'GET',
}));
```

Based on the [documentation](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.xmlHttpRequest), I would expect the `synchronous` option to make the call return a response `object`. Yet, it acts the same way as an async call would; the `onload` handler still works. Was the `synchronous` option disabled? Is there some other way to make a cross-origin request synchronously?

Comment: it will just block ui while this request is sent and a response is received. You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077906/synchronous-cross-domain-request.

Comment: The documentation says **more data will be available in the return value.** But it doesn't say what that information will be, and there are no examples.

Comment: @Barmar if there was any data whatsoever in the return value, it's type would not be `undefined`.

Comment: I think the line saying that more data would be available is just a mistake in the doc.

Comment: You should still be able to make the request synchronously. The `onload` function can set variables in an outer scope and they should be available after the function returns.

Comment: @Barmar you're right! It's too bad the wiki doesn't allow public editors. If you want to post that comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Just curious: what happens if the `onload` function returns something? Maybe that gets returned by `xmlHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Barmar Nope, it always returns undefined.

Comment: AFAIK there should be no way to actually perform GMXHR synchronously in WebExtensions-based Greasemonkey because it involves a cross-process communication which is always asynchronous. Well theoretically maybe you can force Firefox to use just one process though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation that says that the return value will be different when using synchronous mode is wrong. Just set a variable that you use outside of the `onload` function.

```
let returnData;
GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  url: 'https://google.com',
  synchronous: true,
  method: 'GET',
  onload: function(response) {
    returnData = response;
  }
}));
alert(returnData);
```